# Header and footer as a service in Dropwizard?

Tags: web-services, architecture, freemarker, dropwizard, microservices

I have a hypothetical web application which is split up into a microservice architecture like (as an example):
[image: Distributed application structure]

Clients A-C are web applications that serve HTML. Services 1-3 are the backend that handle CRUD and serve JSON. There are other clients (not pictured) that do not access Frontend Service - namely, native clients such as Android and iOS. I'm trying to figure out the best way to serve common frontend content (such as header/footer/css) across all web clients. The best way I can think of doing this is to create a Frontend Service that each web client can access to pull this common information. That way changing the common front end will be reflected in each application immediately without need to update versions, recompile or redeploy.

**My question** is what is the best way of doing this? I'm using Dropwizard to serve both the web clients and the services. The web clients serve Dropwizard Views (with freemarker templates) via Jetty. Is there a way to compose Dropwizard Views so that I can request a Header and a Footer view from Frontend Service and wrap these around each view returned from the Clients? Or am I going about this completely wrong? I know that Freemarker supports template inheritance but as far as I can tell this means the header/footer would have to live in each client or be pulled in from a common JAR (which would require updating version numbers and recompiling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have content synchronized between all the microservices, in your case the header and footer, I'd suggest [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/), it's designed for distributed orchestration and has more of a push model - i.e. you'd update the header in Zookeeper and all of your services would receive that update almost instantly.

I suggest the [Curator](http://curator.apache.org/) library as it's much easier to work with than Zookeeper directly, the [cache example](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=curator.git;a=blob;f=curator-examples/src/main/java/cache/PathCacheExample.java;h=e121337c50ff3ad878720632e9f134a54f5149bb;hb=HEAD) might be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/) as distributed Map/Cache. It is really easy to use (see code examples), but if you want some enterprise features you have to pay a lot.